# InDesign Data Merge with hyperlinks

Tags: website-design, adobe-indesign, data-merge

I want to run a data merge with text and photos and I want to be able to hyperlink the photo to a website. I have about 400 entries with the data merge that will each be on a separate page but I can't for the life of me figure out how to hyperlink the pictures automatically!

Comment: Hi Nicole. You'd be better off asking this question on InDesign Secrets, or possibly the SuperUser site on StackExchange. On gd.se this falls under the heading of "Technical Support," and is considered off-topic. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm open to these kinds of questions here (despite the rules) but you'll get better answers elsewhere. I think you'll have the best luck with an XML workflow. Try asking around on the [Adobe InDesign forums](https://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign). If you want something *really* efficient, go to the [InD Scripting forum](https://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign/indesign_scripting).

Answer (score 1):

InDesign native Datamerge won't allow you to create hyperlinks on the fly. You need at least Scripting to achieve that. A plugin such as EasyCatalog is also a good candidate.